# google piechart pie background image

Tags: image, charts, background, google-visualization

I am using google charts and here is my piechart code...I want to use background repeating image instead of colors. Is that possible with google charts?

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                  ['Work',     1],
                  ['Eat',      1],
                  ['Commute',  1],
                  ['Watch TV', 1],
                  ['Sleep',    1]
                ]);

                var options = {
                    pieSliceBorderColor : 'none',
                    chartArea:{left:5,top:5,width:390,height:390},
                    enableInteractivity:false,
                    pieStartAngle:30,
                    pieHole: 0.6,
                    slices: {
                        0: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.01 },
                        1: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.01  },
                        2: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.01  },
                        3: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.01  },
                        4: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.01  },

                    }
                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

                options.slices[sliceCount].color = 'transparent';
                chart.draw(data, options);


            }
```

Comment: do you mean replace the color of chart slices, or the background of the overall chart?

Comment: chart slices only whitehat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no standard options to fill slices with repeating image

however, you can modify the chart's svg after it finishes drawing

on the `'ready'` event,

create an image pattern and add to svg defs

then replace the `'fill'` attribute on the chart elements that should have the image

pie chart slices are typically drawn with `<path>` elements
when there is only one slice `(100%)`, a `<rect>` element is used
the legend is drawn with `<circle>`

keep in mind, if you need to create an image of the chart,
custom modifications such as these will not work when using method --> `getImageURI`

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
    ['Work',     1],
    ['Eat',      1],
    ['Commute',  1],
    ['Watch TV', 1],
    ['Sleep',    1]
  ]);

  var options = {
    pieSliceBorderColor: 'none',
    pieSliceText: 'none',
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 12,
      left: 12,
      top: 12,
      width: 390,
      height:390
    },
    enableInteractivity: false,
    pieStartAngle: 30,
    pieHole: 0.6,
    slices: {
      0: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.1 },
      1: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.1 },
      2: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.1 },
      3: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.1 },
      4: { color: 'brown', offset: 0.1 },
    }
  };

  var container = $('#piechart')[0];
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // create image pattern
    var svgNS = $('svg')[0].namespaceURI;
    var pattern = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'pattern');
    pattern.setAttribute('id', 'whiteHat');
    pattern.setAttribute('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse');
    pattern.setAttribute('width', 16);
    pattern.setAttribute('height', 16);
    var image = document.createElementNS(svgNS, 'image');
    image.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/512/star_wars/16/clone_old.png');
    image.setAttribute('x', 0);
    image.setAttribute('y', 0);
    image.setAttribute('width', 16);
    image.setAttribute('height', 16);
    pattern.appendChild(image);
    $('#defs')[0].appendChild(pattern);

    // add image to pie slices
    $('svg path').attr('fill', 'url(#whiteHat)');

    // add image to legend circles
    $('svg circle').attr('fill', 'url(#whiteHat)');

    // test chart image
    $(container.parentNode).append('<img alt="Chart" src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">');
  });
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>piechart</div>
<div id="piechart"></div>
<div>image</div>
```

Comment: great it works...thanks so much whitehat...but there is another problem for me...I didnt write in my question...what if I want to make one slice background transparent and others with image?

Comment: the slices in the svg dom should be in the same order as in the data table used to draw the chart

Comment: ok right...solved...last question...I used one more chart on same page...and your pattern affecting both charts...I want to use it only one chart...first one for example...what do you say whitehat?

Comment: you'll need to narrow the selectors to the specific chart divs, including svg, defs, path, circle --> `$('#piechart svg')`, `$('#piechart defs')`, etc...

Comment: ok great thanks it worked...do you have any idea about slice texts with linebreak? I used \n but it not worked...I have some slice text with multiple words...

Comment: no easy way -- could clone existing `<text>` node, change text, and align underneath...